# Making a HTML Tagged email in php

Tags: php, html

I want to create an HTML Message to send an email in PHP.

```
$message = $mess0 . "</br>" . $mess1 . "</br>" . $mess2 . "</br>" .  $mes1 . "</br></br>" . $mes2 . "</br>" . $mes23 . "</br></br>" . $mes3  . "</br></br>" .  $mes4 . "</br>" . $mes5 . "</br>" . $mes6 . "</br>" . $mes7 . "</br>" .  $mes8 . "</br>" .  $mes9 .  "</br></br>" . $mes10 ;

$message =  <html><body><p>$message</p></body></html>;
```

Here are some variables.

I am getting the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/thevowaa/public_html/iphoneapp/webservice/file.php on line 214

Comment: It looks like your second line of PHP isn't using quotes to indicate a string, which is creating your parse error. Unless that's a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add HTML tags between double quotes.

```
$message = "<html><body><p>".$message."</p></body></html>";
```

Comment: please add a little explanation, Tom. otherwise a good answer

Comment: it happens. I would like to know about whether or not you can put the Variable inside the quotes or not though

Comment: You can add variables inside double quotes and they will be parsed, but not inside single quotes. Inside single quotes $foo will remain litterally $foo

Answer (score 1):

Where are the double quotes see below

```
$message =  "<html><body><p>$message</p></body></html>";
```

Comment: don't you need to un quote the `$message` variable inside that string?

Comment: please post a link or some other evidence to back this up dianuj

Comment: inside `"` you can but inside of `'` you can't.  you should post this inside of your answer.  I still think that this would be bad code practice.

Comment: @dianuj - I think you should use one of the following. `$message =  "<html><body><p>" . $message . "</p></body></html>";` or `$message =  "<html><body><p>{$message}</p></body></html>";`

Comment: @Malachi See this fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/h91-rbs all your answer is in this

Comment: dianuj, neither his nor your code works on that first site you linked to

Comment: just saw the fiddle. it does work in that fiddle. but I still think that it would be bad coding practice to have the variable inside of the quotes

Comment: @Malachi you have to run the code there is a button use some common sense :) they clearly placed the button with F9 shortkey too  :)

Comment: @dianuj +1, you are right but I remember that I got error when I tried this. I don't know maybe my PHP version was different (older) what do you think?

Comment: @Malachi Variable interpolation is a standard feature of PHP, why not take advantage of it? It's not the best practice to use complex expressions in interpolation (`"Some string {$arr["one"]["two"] + $arr["three"]["four"]}"`) which could get out of hand quickly and make it difficult to follow. But there is nothing wrong with: `"<h1>Hello $name<h1>"`.

Comment: @dianuj, the `phpfiddle` site works, the `writecodeonline` does not

Comment: @izuriel Totally agree with you that's what i tried to show Malachi

Comment: @Malachi writecodeonline works for me this site does not stores your code and neither gives permalink so i can't provide the demo of the code

Comment: no biggie, add the explanation of the variable interpolation to your answer. far quicker than going back and forth about in comments

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to hold HTML in PHP variable. You can use single quote or double quotes. You also need to put a dot(.) before and after single/double quotes.  Your PHP string could be constructed in following two ways:

```
$message =  '<html><body><p>'.$message.'</p></body></html>';
```

or like this,

```
$message =  "<html><body><p>".$message."</p></body></html>";
```

Also, use of single quotes(') is encouraged in PHP coding because it's doesn't clash with javascript or css double quotes(") when constructing html pages using PHP.

For more information on usage of quotes in PHP, check out this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)